# Low Search - Question about search mode behaviour

Tags: low-search

I have a low search form

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="test" secure="no" search_mode="any" result_page="results/page"}
    <input type="text" name="keyword" />
    <select name="search:my_field" id="my_field">
        <option></option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="foo bar">foo bar</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

I have two entries in the test channel. One of them has the my_field value "foo" and the other one has "foo bar".

When I choose "foo", I get both entries.
When I choose "foo bar", I get one entry(the one whose my_field value is "foo bar").

It seems to me that this is caused by the param search_mode="any".

Is there any way to make my_field use exact text search while still retaining full text search for the rest of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting keyword searches and the `search:my_field` parameter mixed up. The `search_mode` parameter **only** applies to **keywords**. The keywords are used to search the index using full text (if applicable).

The `search:my_field` input fields you're using is identical to setting the channel:entries parameter and will filter results [as described in the EE docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name). This is native filtering and therefore *doesn't* use full text. You *can* use the [exact matching syntax](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#exact-matching) in your `<select>` by prefixing the values with a `=`.

```
<select name="search:my_field" id="my_field">
    <option></option>
    <option value="=foo">foo</option>
    <option value="=foo bar">foo bar</option>
</select>
```